# How to group by key and retrieve keys from the grouped elements?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to `group` and `sum` dicts from a `DataFrame` like this:

```
dt = [
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': True, 'code': 'x'},
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': True, 'code': 'x1'},
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': False, 'code': 'x2'}
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(dt).groupby('is_cumulative')
result = df.sum()
```

The result is:

```
               discount_value
is_cumulative                
False                      10
True                       20
```

But i need to get all "code" key used to sum the final resultt, e.g:

```
result['discount_value'][True]  # 20
# how to get the codes "x" and "x1"?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```py
import pandas 
dt = [
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': True, 'code': 'x'},
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': True, 'code': 'x1'},
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': False, 'code': 'x2'}
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(dt).groupby('is_cumulative')
result = df.agg({'discount_value':sum, 'code':list})
print(result)
```

The output:

```
               discount_value     code
is_cumulative                         
False                      10     [x2]
True                       20  [x, x1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a little differently:

```
dt = [
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': True, 'code': 'x'},
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': True, 'code': 'x1'},
    {'discount_value': 10, 'is_cumulative': False, 'code': 'x2'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dt)                         # here
result = df.groupby('is_cumulative').sum()    # and here

# get the code
df.loc[df.is_cumulative, 'code']
```

Output:

```
0     x
1    x1
Name: code, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dt)
df = df.groupby(by=['is_cumulative']).agg({'code': ','.join, 'discount_value': 'sum'})
print(df)
print('codes = {}'.format(df.loc[True]['code']))

               code  discount_value
is_cumulative
False            x2              10
True           x,x1              20

codes = x,x1
```